# How to change default site title in sensenet ECM?

Tags: html, sensenet

I am trying to replace Sense/Net default site title (Sense/Net ECM Demo Site).
I've changed the text in the file system and in the content explorer too. I changed the text to "my document portal" but it displays "Portalen-USmy document portal" as the title.  I changed "SenseNetDemoSiteTitle" to "my document portal" in

```
<title><%=HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject( "Portal", "my document portal ")%></title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it simply to

```
<title>my document portal</title>
```

Comment: Here is my changes : <title><%=HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Portal", ">my document portal")%></title> but it showing "Portalen-USmy document portal"

Comment: as I advised in my answer change the title to
<title>my document portal</title>
The httpcontext... stuff is not needed only 'my document portal''

Comment: Done. but why <title><%=HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Portal", "SenseNetDemoSiteTitle")%></title> is in code?

Comment: It is a localized string. If you want to use your site in multiple languages, it is possible to add your text in multiple languages into a localization file and then the text can be displayed differently, when one user browse your site in english and another for example in german. 
If you're interested in localization in sensenet, check this wiki article: http://wiki.sensenet.com/Localization

Comment: Okay.got it. since morning i was reading about GetGlobalResourceObject :p

Comment: It showing change only on main page. Whenever i click or go to other pages still little shows the "Sense/Net ECM Demo Site" where should i change the title which reflect on all pages?

Comment: The other pages have other pagetemplates (html files in the /Root/Global/pagetemplates folder), check which ones are used on the related pages (the info is on the Portal Remote Controller). Or change the localized value in the resource file (/Root/Localization/PortalResources.xml)

Comment: I changed in Root/Localization/PortalResources.xml but still it showing default title ;(

Comment: Have you change it in the Content Explorer?

Comment: in which page template file i have to change?

Comment: You can check it on the Portal Remote Control. Open it on the page on which you want to change the title and it is listed in the middle of the infos.

Comment: okay. But this way i have to change title for every page individually?

Comment: Yes, or you can change it once in the resource file at the language that you use on the site. So if you've changed it in the resource file, check that it is also changed in the Content Explorer not only in the file system, and check also that it is changed in the language that you used (by default there're english and hungarian part of all the resource classes if you've set the site's language to english you have to change it in the english part)

Comment: okay. i am using English (it comes by default) with language i have no issue, i am just trying to replace default site title for whole system.

Comment: Did you change it this way? https://demo06.demo.sensenet.com/Root/Sites/Default_Site/features/Galleries/Image%20Library%20Ipsum/loc.png